# Returning a semi-unique set of most recent records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my application a User has Highlights.

Each Highlight has a HighlightType. So if I run `user.highlights` I might see an output like this:

[image: example of user.highlights]

Notice that there are many highlights of type_id 47. This marks milestones of the number of times the user has gone running.

What I would like to do is return this full list of records, but only include one highlight for each highlight_type, and I want that one record to be the most recent record (in this case the "50th run" highlight). So in the example above I would get the same results but with IDs 195-199 removed.

Is there an efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried `user.highlights.group('highlight_type_id')` ?

Comment: This appears to "work" but I'm not sure what it's actually doing. GROUP does return one record per highlight_type_id but I'm not sure what logic it uses to select the particular record. As 244an suggests, when something like user.highlights.group('highlight_type_id').order('created_at DESC') doesn't work as hoped, as the ordering is done after the grouping. If I could understand the logic behind group's selection of the record I could be more confident in this approach.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an easy or clean way to achieve that, nor a "Rails way". Look at e.g. this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

According to one suggestion in that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group) you would do this SQL request:

```
SELECT h1.*
FROM highlights h1
LEFT JOIN highlights h2
 ON (h1.user_id = h2.user_id 
     AND h1.highlight_type_id = h2.highlight_type_id
     AND h1.created_at < h2.created_at)
WHERE h2.id IS NULL AND h1.user_id = <the user id you are interested in>
group by h1.highlight_type_id
```

I think it will be some performance problem if you have big tables maybe, an it not so very clean I think.

Otherwise, if there isn't so much highlights for a user I would have done something like this:

```
rows = {}
user.highlights.order('highlight_type_id, created_at DESC').each do |hi|
  rows[hi.highlight_type_id] ||= hi
end
# then use rows which will have one object for each highlight_type_id
```

The `DESC` on created_at is important

**EDIT:**
I also saw some suggestions based on this
`user.highlights.group('highlight_type_id').order('created_at DESC')`
And that was also how I first thought it should be solved, but I tested it and it doesn't seems to get a correct result - at least on my test data.

Comment: Great points here. I like your second suggestion, as it's easy to understand. A typical user will have ~50 highlight records, and at upper bounds this may reach something like ~200 records. Any idea if this could be a performance concern?

Comment: Also for my particular situation, I'm considering just adding a flag to the table where I flag the old records of a highlight_type_id. Then I could just filter these out. Seems like a cleaner solution, ya? Either way still curious if there is a clean, performant way of solving this without a flag.

Comment: Don't know what server you use, but we have servers that are 4 years old. In some places we treat results from up to 20 000 db rows as model objects without memory issues. For performance, as long as it's some hundred rows I don't think you will notice if it's one ore some hundred. Using a flag seems like a "clean" solution, but it depends on that that flag is always correct. Me personally would have used the "Hash solution". I think the "JOIN solution" can have bad performance.

Comment: I'm also curious if there is a clean and elegant solution to this, my suggestions is kind of poor mans solutions :)